# how to lock a GPIO pin configuration in stm32f4?

Tags: embedded, stm32

I am implementing my own version for stm32f407 drivers. so I came to that section mentioning how to lock a GPIO pin configuration and that's what they said on the [reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0090-stm32f405415-stm32f407417-stm32f427437-and-stm32f429439-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) page 285:

```
LOCK key write sequence:
WR LCKR[16] = ‘1’ + LCKR[15:0]
WR LCKR[16] = ‘0’ + LCKR[15:0]
WR LCKR[16] = ‘1’ + LCKR[15:0]
RD LCKR
RD LCKR[16] = ‘1’ (this read operation is optional but it confirms that the lock is active)
```

The problem is that I don't understand what `LCKR[16] = ‘1’ + LCKR[15:0]` means. As `LCKR[16]` is only **1-bit** while `‘1’ + LCKR[15:0]` is **16 bits**, how shall I assign a **16-bit** value to a **1-bit** value? and why `‘0’ + LCKR[15:0]` is even written like that? isn't `‘0’ + LCKR[15:0]` same as `LCKR[15:0]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that I don't understand what LCKR[16] = ‘1’ +
> LCKR[15:0] means.

It is a bit confusing notation. It should be:

```
WR LCKR = (LCKR[16] = ‘1’) + LCKR[15:0].
WR LCKR = (LCKR[16] = ‘0’) + LCKR[15:0]
WR LCKR = (LCKR[16] = ‘1’) + LCKR[15:0]
RD LCKR
RD (LCKR[16] = ‘1’)
```

In C language it will be:

```
/**
 * @fn int lockPins(GPIO_TypeDef*, uint16_t)
 * @brief locks / unlocks the pins
 * 

 * @param gpio - gpio to be locked
 * @param pins pins. Bits from 0 to 15 represents pins
 * @return 1 if lock was successful 
 */
int lockPins(GPIO_TypeDef *gpio, uint16_t pins)
{
    gpio -> LCKR = (1 << 16) | pins;
    gpio -> LCKR = pins;
    gpio -> LCKR = (1 << 16) | pins;    
    (void)gpio -> LCKR;
    return !!(gpio -> LCKR & (1 << 16));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should not write only to bit 16. Access to this register is 32-bit.
[image]

For example if you want to lock pins 0 and 9 on GPIOx port, your lock sequence will be like this:

```
GPIOx->LCKR = 0x00010201; // bits 0 and 9 of LCK[15:0] are set
GPIOx->LCKR = 0x00000201;
GPIOx->LCKR = 0x00010201;
(void)GPIOx->LCKR;
```

Comment: it is an invalid sequence;